# Youtube Player API - Only plays browser tab is selected

Tags: youtube

I am currently developing a site using the youtube player api (chromeless, to be exact.) I have created a script dealing with playing the videos in a playlist but if the page is not focused or the tab is not selected in the browser the video will not start. Is there any possible hack or way to by pass this and for the player to continuously play while viewing other browser tabs?

Comment: What is the value that player.getPlayerState() returns when it lose the focus?

Answer (score 0):

There is no code on the youtube side to restrict playback in inactive tabs - this sounds like an issue with your computer or browser.